# Accesing Array in an array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array of 3 columns in which I have the second column which is an array in php.The second column which is an array can have 2-6 rows.

I put the data in the array with key with the below code

```
$data_array = array(
                  'name' =>$name, 
                  'category_name'=>$category_name,
                  'url'=>$url

);
```

The second column $category_name in the above $data_array is an array which has data like below

```
$category_name = array("India", "USA", "UK");
```

I want to echo the the data in the following format and eventually add it the mysql database

```
'Jim'
'India'
'www.google.com'

'Jim'
'USA'
'www.google.com'

'Jim'
'UK'
'www.google.com'

'John'
'India'
'www.yahoo.com'

'John'
'USA'
'www.yahoo.com'

'John'
'UK'
'www.yahoo.com'
```

If you notice the first and third row remain same and the second row changes according to the data in the category_name array

I am trying to use the below code to achieve this but I am getting no output

```
for($i=0;$i<count($NPR);$i++){

for($j=0;$j<count($NPR[$i]['category_name'][j]);$j++){

echo "'".$NPR[$i]['name']."'<br>";
echo "'".$NPR[$i]['category_name'][j]."'<br>";
echo "'".$NPR[$i]['url']."'<br>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `count($NPR[$i]['category_name'])`, you added an unnecessary `[j]` at the end of this.

But it all would be easier if you used `foreach`

```
foreach ($NPR as $item) {
    foreach ($item['category_name'] AS $cat) {
        echo "'{$item['name']}'<br>";
        echo "'$cat'<br>";
        echo "'{$item['url']}'<br>";
    }
}
```

Make sure you have error reporting enabled when you're debugging code. `[j]` should have produced a warning.

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar. I was trying to count the number of columns in the array $category_name by adding [j] in count($NPR[$i]['category_name'][j])